Branch protection rule is not allowing me to push changes in same branch second time in github
I created a branch feature/EAB-123 from the **test **branch using the following command:
git checkout -b feature/EAB-123 test
The branch was created successfully. I made changes, committed them, and pushed them without any issues.
Later, I made additional changes in the same branch, committed them, and tried to push again. However, I encountered the following error:
error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/feature/EAB-123. remote: error: Changes must be made through a pull request. To https://github.com/vijay/projects.git ! [remote rejected]   feature/EAB-123 -> feature/EAB-123 (protected branch hook declined)
It appears that the branch feature/EAB-123 is protected, and changes must be made through a pull request. How can I resolve this issue and push my changes?
What I tried:
I created the branch feature/EAB-123 from test and pushed the initial changes successfully.
I made further changes, committed them, and attempted to push again.
What I expected:
I expected the changes to be pushed successfully to the feature/EAB-123 branch.
Constraints:

I do not want to create another branch from feature/EAB-123 and push, then create a pull request.
I do not want to bypass the branch protection rules for specific users or branches, as this would not comply with SOC2 certification requirements.

Given these constraints, please suggest a solid solution for resolving this issue.

Did the first push create the branch on the remote? And was the branch protection added between the first and second push or was it already there?

Side note, it's kind of weird to have branch protection on feature branches. Normally you only protect long-lived shared branches such as main, master, develop, release, etc.

yes, first push created branch on remote and branch protection is already added before both push

OK. So it seems you can push a branch once, and from then on you must do a PR. Maybe you can delete the branch and re-push it. (Though, I suspect protection will prevent that as well.) You might have to resort to pushing different names for every version, and that is kind of silly. Do you know if the protection on feature branches is intentional? Maybe you can just turn it off for feature branches, and only have it for specific branches.

BTW, this statement is probably not true: "I do not want to bypass the branch protection rules for specific users or branches, as this would not comply with SOC2 certification requirements." It doesn't make sense that you can push whatever you want the first time, but not the second push. Whatever you wanted to push the second time could have been pushed the first time without protection. The solution is to have specific shared branches with protection on it, say, main, and only builds which are deployed to production can come from main. Features PR into main.
